# Batch Script - How to copy folder and its contents to parent directory?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a folder structure where there are multiple folders with the same name like Release & Debug.

There is a "Backup folder" and "Batch file" at the top level.

**Folder structure:**

```
Solution -> Project1 -> bin -> Release folder, Debug folder
Solution -> Project2 -> bin -> Release folder, Debug folder
Solution -> Project3 -> bin -> Release folder, Debug folder
Solution -> Project4 -> bin -> Release folder, Debug folder
Solution -> Backup folder
Solution -> BackupUtility.bat
```

I am trying to copy all the folders and create a backup in the Backup folder using the below batch script.

**Expected backup folder structure:**

```
Solution -> Backup -> Backup_2021-09-16 19.37.00 -> Project1_Release folder, Project1_Debug folder
Solution -> Backup -> Backup_2021-09-16 19.37.00 -> Project2_Release folder, Project1_Debug folder
Solution -> Backup -> Backup_2021-09-16 19.37.00 -> Project3_Release folder, Project1_Debug folder
Solution -> Backup -> Backup_2021-09-16 19.37.00 -> Project4_Release folder, Project1_Debug folder
Solution -> Backup -> Backup_2021-09-16 19.37.00 -> Project5_Release folder, Project1_Debug folder
```

**Current Script:**

```
@echo off   
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

call :GET_CUR_GRA_PAR_APPENDED_FOLDER_NAME "D:Solution\Project1\bin\Release" appendedPathTemp
@echo Appended Path: %appendedPathTemp%

:: PROVIDED PATH PARENT WITH BACKSLASH
set currentDirectoryWithBackslash=%~dp0
@echo CURRENT DIRECTORY WITH BACKSLASH: "%currentDirectoryWithBackslash%" &echo\

:: PROVIDED PATH PARENT WITH BACKSLASH
set currentDirectoryWithBackslash=%__CD__%
@echo CURRENT DIRECTORY WITH BACKSLASH: "%currentDirectoryWithBackslash%" &echo\

:: PROVIDED PATH PARENT WITHOUT BACKSLASH
set currentDirectoryWithoutBackslash=%CD%
@echo CURRENT DIRECTORY WITHOUT BACKSLASH: "%currentDirectoryWithoutBackslash%" &echo\

:: BACKUP DIRECTORY PATH
set backupDirectoryPath=%CD%\Backup
@echo BACKUP DIRECTORY PATH: "%backupDirectoryPath%" &echo\

:: CURRENT DATE TIME
set currentDateTime=%DATE:~6,4%-%DATE:~3,2%-%DATE:~0,2% %TIME:~0,2%.%TIME:~3,2%.%TIME:~6,2%
@echo CURRENT DATE TIME: "%currentDateTime%" &echo\

:: CURRENT BACKUP DIRECTORY
set currentBackupDirectory=%backupDirectoryPath%\Backup_%currentDateTime%
@echo Current Backup Directory: "%currentBackupDirectory%" &echo\

@echo Taking backup of all Debug, Release and Publish folder's. &echo\

mkdir "%currentBackupDirectory%"

for /d /r . %%d in (Debug,Release,Publish) do @if exist "%%d" (
call :GET_CUR_GRA_PAR_APPENDED_FOLDER_NAME "D:Solution\Project1\bin\Release" appendedPathInLoop
@echo Appended Path In Loop: %appendedPathInLoop%
robocopy "%%d" "%currentBackupDirectory%\%appendedPathInLoop%" /E /LOG+:"%currentBackupDirectory%\Backup_Log.txt"
)

@echo Debug, Release and Publish folder's backup successfull. Enter any key to close the window. &echo\
pause > nul

:GET_CUR_GRA_PAR_APPENDED_FOLDER_NAME
set "_path=%~1"
echo PROVIDED PATH: %_path%
for %%a in ("%_path%") do set "provided_path_name=%%~nxa"
echo PROVIDED PATH NAME: %provided_path_name%
for %%a in ("%_path%") do set "provided_path_parent_path=%%~dpa"
echo PROVIDED PATH PARENT PATH: %provided_path_parent_path%
for %%a in (%provided_path_parent_path:~0,-1%) do set "provided_path_parent_name=%%~nxa"
echo PROVIDED PATH PARENT NAME: %provided_path_parent_name%
for %%a in (%provided_path_parent_path:~0,-1%) do set "provided_path_grand_parent_path=%%~dpa"
echo PROVIDED PATH GRAND PARENT PATH: %provided_path_grand_parent_path%
for %%a in (%provided_path_grand_parent_path:~0,-1%) do set "provided_path_grand_parent_name=%%~nxa"
echo PROVIDED PATH GRAND PARENT NAME: %provided_path_grand_parent_name%
echo PROVIDED PATH AND GRAND PARENT APPENDED NAME: %provided_path_grand_parent_name%_%provided_path_name%
set "%~2=%provided_path_grand_parent_name%_%provided_path_name%"
EXIT /B 0
```

How to generate this folder name*(GrandParentFolderName_FolderName)* dynamically inside for loop?

How to get the Grand Parent folder name?

**After modifications:**

Now I am able to write a `function` to get the desired folder name which I am testing at the beginning of the script, but inside for loop, `it is coming empty`. I also tried setting `enabledelayedexpansion` but still no change.

Comment: Line 4. is incorrect, it should read `set "currentDirectoryWithBackslash=%__CD__%"`, or `set "currentDirectoryWithBackslash=%CD%\"`. `%~dp0` is the location of the running batch file with a backward slash, and that is most certainly only also the currect directory in very specific circumstances. So depending upon those circumstances, perhaps your line 4. is correct and your lines 3. and 5. are incorrect instead!

Comment: @Compo That will be corrected. Thanks for the info. Any suggestions of getting the folder name inside for loop?

Comment: Line 16. `set currentDateTime=%DATE:~6,4%-%DATE:~3,2%-%DATE:~0,2% %TIME:~0,2%.%TIME:~3,2%.%TIME:~6,2%` will only be possibly correct for your current users PC locale and configuaration settings. there are much more robust ways of defining the date and time which are irrespective of those scenarios, please use the search facility to locate one or other of them, if you ever intend to run this script on any other PC, for a different user, or even possibly on your next configured Operating System installation.

Comment: `for /d /r . %%d in (Debug,Release)` is not what you should be using either. Try `For /F "EOL=? Delims=" %%d In ('Dir "Debug" "Release" /B /S /A:D-L-R-S 2^>NUL')` instead. Then you can get rid of the `if exist "%%d"` part, as it will no longer be required.

Comment: @Compo I have made some changes and wrote a function. My current issue is folder name not getting retained inside for loop. Any idea how to fix it. Please check "After modifications:" section to know more details.

Comment: Nithin B, if you are still asking for my advice, it suggests that you feel it may be of value to you. However, whilst I could accept that you have decided that there's no need to modify your date and time generation code, in this case, I cannot accept that you have decided to ignore my latest comment. I advised that you change something, and what to change it to, but you have not done that, so it appears that you feel that your code is better. How does that motivate me to provide any further advice?

Comment: @Compo If it's of no value. Why would anyone ask a question on this platform :) I have a couple of set statements that I am not even using because I am exploring batch programming and not deleting anything. I also have added your 1st comment suggestion in the script. At some point, I will be 100% adding your other 2 suggestions too(Without deleting the existing scripts because it's learning code for me). I also upvoted your code suggestions because I found them valuable.

Comment: Nithin B, open up a Command Prompt window, navigate to your intended current directory, then type `for /d /r . %d in (Debug,Release) do @echo %d` and press the `[ENTER]` key. Now take a look at what it outputs, and tell me why you would want to pass every one of those locations out of the loop into an `if exist` command, just to output the actual target subdirectories. Efficient code is of value, so start by using it, otherwise I will not provide you with the assistance you need. You seem to be asking for advice from others with knowledge you don't have, but then acting like you know better.

Comment: @Compo I never mentioned it's of no value. As I told I will be keeping all code because it's a learning exercise for me. I have solved it now by calling robocopy directly inside the function instead of returning from it. Obviously, it will not be an efficient solution and could fail in a couple of cases because I am not an expert like you in Batch Programming. I will be posting my answer. I will make no changes to the question but will add your suggestions to the answer. Would like to see an efficient answer from you so that I can mark it as an answer to this question. Thanks. Cheers. :)